# Update MySQL table with another table's data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727827/update-one-mysql-table-with-values-from-another) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202075/advanced-mysql-query-update-table-with-info-from-another-table), but I need to make a GROUP BY query to set another table.

`logintable` is like this:

```
id | name    | login_date
------------------------
1  | michael | 2013-01-04 
2  | michael | 2013-01-08 
3  | mary    | 2013-01-11 
4  | john    | 2013-01-15 
5  | michael | 2013-01-19 
6  | mary    | 2013-01-22 
7  | john    | 2013-01-26
```

I make a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM logintable GROUP BY name ORDER BY id ASC
```

This gives me first login date of the users:

```
1  | michael | 2013-01-04 
3  | mary    | 2013-01-11 
4  | john    | 2013-01-15
```

I have another table called `userstable` like this:

```
id | name    | last_seen_date | first_login_date
------------------------------------------------
1  | michael | 2013-02-02     |  
2  | john    | 2013-02-04     |   
3  | mary    | 2013-02-16     |
```

I need to update userstable's first_login_date column, with the first result. How can I do this ?
(I have 75k records in logintable and 10k records in userstable)

Comment: You mean like INSERT...SELECT, except for UPDATE?  You should just UPDATE with a JOIN or two.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to give you the first login date. Use `MIN(login_date)` instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
UPDATE  userstable a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  name, min(login_date) min_date
            FROM    logintable
            GROUP   BY name
        ) b ON a.name = b.Name
SET     a.first_login_table = b.min_date
```

for faster performance, you need to add an `INDEX` on column `Name` for both tables. This will **prevent from performing full table scan** which is very slow in large databases.

Adding `INDEX` on table `userstable`:

```
ALTER TABLE usersTable ADD INDEX (Name);
```

for referential integrity, make table `logintable` dependent on table `userstable` by defining `FOREIGN KEY` constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE loginTable ADD CONSTRAINT tb_fk
FOREIGN KEY (Name) REFRENCES usersTable (Name)
```

Comment: One more thing please. What if I want to set "first_login_table" column if column record is NULL. Can I add "WHERE a.first_login_table NOT NULL" in the end of the query?

Comment: add `WHERE a.first_login_table IS NULL` to set only if the column is null

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE userstable AS u
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT MIN(login_date) AS MinLoginDate, Name
   FROM logintable 
   GROUP BY name
) AS l ON u.name = l.name
SET u.first_login_date = l.MinLoginDate
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know MySql...but in SQL Server you would write something like this:

```
UPDATE userstable set first_login_date = (SELECT MIN(login_date) FROM logintable where name = userstable.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE  userstable a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  name, min(login_date) min_date
            FROM    logintable
            GROUP   BY name
        ) b ON a.name = b.Name
SET     a.first_login_table = b.min_date

This will definitely show your output.