# Update Table to last ID from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run something like

```
 UPDATE TABLE profile
 SET profile_photo = (SELECT photo_id FROM photos WHERE profile_id 
 = 'someprofileid' ORDER BY photo_id DESC LIMIT 1;)
 WHERE 'somecolumn' = 'some criteria'
```

I have seen [Advanced MySql Query: Update table with info from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202075/advanced-mysql-query-update-table-with-info-from-another-table)

But I only want the last entry which satisfies the `WHERE` clause, therefore the `DESC` and `LIMIT 1`. How do I included these criteria in the `SET` information?

(My goal is to update change a profile picture to the most recent profile picture, after e.g a delete or sth)

Comment: remove ; after limit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use select query with limit and desc and get id and fire update on that id simple

Answer (score 1):

`update` supports `order by` and `limit`:

```
 UPDATE TABLE profile p
     SET profile_photo = (SELECT photo_id
                          FROM photos ph
                          WHERE ph.profile_id = 'someprofileid'
                          ORDER BY photo_id DESC
                          LIMIT 1
                         )
     WHERE p.'somecolumn' = 'some criteria'
     ORDER BY p.id DESC   -- you need to order by something
     LIMIT 1;
```